# VujeJS behind Nginx and SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, vue.js, load-balancing

I've put VueJS behind Nginx with SSL, now I receive connection errors in browser because VueJS seems to use same host address for Websockets. Even after I've put

```
host: '0.0.0.0'
```

in config/index.js I receive

```
 https://project_url:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1537807561631 0 ()
```

how can I change the websocket server address to point it to Nginx?

Comment: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node "Often WebSockets don't play nicely with proxies and load balancers. Deploying a SockJS server behind Nginx or Apache could be painful."

Comment: I think you are mixing development configuration (using the dev server setup by vue-cli with hot module reloading) with the production configuration (nginx and SSL). Serving with vue-cli should be used only for development. For production you need to build your app and serve it as static files with nginx.

Comment: You are right, but I need to implement Facebook login. And soon it will be SSL only.